# Pointfree Join Array to String, by key in object, in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pointfree, ramda.js

Can [this](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.21.0#?code=var%20joinByKey%20%3D%20R.curry%28function%28key%2C%20model%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20R.assoc%28key%2C%20R.join%28%27%2C%27%20%2CR.prop%28key%2C%20model%29%29%2C%20model%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20input%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%271%27%2C%20%272%27%2C%20%273%27%5D%20%7D%3B%0Avar%20result%20%3D%20joinByKey%28%22a%22%2C%20input%29%3B%0Aresult%3B) be done pointfree?

```
var joinByKey = R.curry(function(key, model){
    return R.assoc(key, R.join(',' ,R.prop(key, model)), model);
});

var input = { a: ['1', '2', '3'] };
var result = joinByKey("a", input); // {"a": "1,2,3"}
```

Comment: Pretty much every expression can be represented with point-free compositions but it doesn't mean you should. In particular, the `R.assoc` has a very complex function signature which makes it very difficult to compose. I promise you that the point-free notation of your particular function, whatever it may be, will be gibberish and hurt your brain. Your function is readable and works, so just keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done like this :

```
const joinByKey = key => R.over(
    R.lensProp(key),
    R.join(',')
);

const input = { a: ['1', '2', '3'] };
const result = joinByKey("a")(input); // {"a": "1,2,3"}
```

If you want to use it uncurrified :

```
const joinByKey = R.curry((key, model) => R.over(
  R.lensProp(key),
  R.join(',')
)(model));

var input = { a: ['1', '2', '3'] };
joinByKey("a", input); // {"a": "1,2,3"}
```

The second one works both currified or uncurrified.

I find it more readable than your version, in contrary of what @naomik says ...

Comment: Awesome solution! But I can't get it to work. `result` is a `_curry1`-function

Comment: It works here : 
http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20joinByKey%20%3D%20key%20%3D%3E%20over%28%0A%20%20lensProp%28key%29%2C%0A%20%20join%28%27%2C%27%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20input%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%271%27%2C%20%272%27%2C%20%273%27%5D%20%7D%3B%0AjoinByKey%28%22a%22%29%28input%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%22a%22%3A%20%221%2C2%2C3%22%7D%0A

Comment: There seems to be a difference between `joinByKey("a", input);` and `joinByKey("a")(input)`

Comment: You're right ... I edited my answer to include both currified and uncurrified versions

Comment: This is still more readable imho ... which is the aim right ?